# 1064 error in MySql request

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following PHP code:

```
function get_all_labels_by_language_id($language_code, $page_index, $user_id) {
    $language_id = $this->get_language_id($language_code);
    $users_query = "select  eng.label_value, loc.votes, loc.user_id, loc.approved, eng.language_value,       
            coalesce(loc.language_value)
            from    labels eng
            left outer join    
                labels loc
            on      loc.language = " . $language_id . "
            and eng.label_value = loc.label_value
            and loc.user_id = '" . $user_id . "'
            where   eng.language = 45
            order by loc.language_value";
    $data = $this->db->query($users_query)->result_array();
    $result = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
        $result[$i]['language_id'] = $language_id;
        if (!$data[$i]['user_id']) {
            $result[$i]['translate'] = $data[$i];
            $result[$i]['alternatives'] = NULL;

            $other_records_query = "select  eng.label_value, loc.votes, loc.user_id, loc.approved, eng.language_value,       
                coalesce(loc.language_value)
                from    labels eng
            left outer join    
                labels loc
            on      loc.language = " . $language_id . "
            and eng.label_value = loc.label_value
            where   eng.language = 45 and loc.label_value='" . $data[$i]['label_value'] . "'
            order by loc.language_value";
            $other_records = $this->db->query($other_records_query)->result_array();
            for ($k = 0; $k < count($other_records); $k++) {
                if ($other_records[$k]['approved'] == '1') {
                    $result[$i]['translate'] = $other_records[$k];
                } else {
                    $result[$i]['alternatives'][] = $other_records[$k];
                }
            }
        } else {
            $result[$i]['translate'] = $data[$i];
            $result[$i]['alternatives'] = NULL;
            if ($data[$i]['approved'] == '1') {
                $other_records_query = "select  eng.label_value, loc.votes, loc.user_id, loc.approved, eng.language_value,       
                coalesce(loc.language_value)
                from    labels eng
            left outer join    
                labels loc
            on      loc.language = " . $language_id . "
                    and eng.label_value = loc.label_value
                    and loc.approved='1'
            where   eng.language = 45 and loc.label_value='" . $data[$i]['label_value'] . "'
            and approved='0' order by loc.language_value";
                $other_records = $this->db->query($other_records_query)->result_array();
                for ($k = 0; $k < count($other_records); $k++) {
                    $result[$i]['alternatives'][] = $other_records[$k];
                }
            } else {
                $other_records_query = "select  eng.label_value, loc.votes, loc.user_id, loc.approved, eng.language_value,       
                coalesce(loc.language_value)
                from    labels eng
            left outer join    
                labels loc
            on      loc.language = " . $language_id . "
                    and eng.label_value = loc.label_value
                    and loc.approved='1'
            where   eng.language = 45 and loc.label_value='" . $data[$i]['label_value'] . "'
            order by loc.language_value";
                $other_records = $this->db->query($other_records_query)->result_array();
                for ($k = 0; $k < count($other_records); $k++) {
                    $result[$i]['alternatives'][] = $other_records[$k];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This code works right, but now I've got the following error:

Error Number: 1064

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't set up correctly. If you're the store owner, please refer to' ' at line 8

select eng.label_value, loc.votes, loc.user_id, loc.approved, eng.language_value, coalesce(loc.language_value) from labels eng left outer join labels loc on loc.language = 24 and eng.label_value = loc.label_value where eng.language = 45 and loc.label_value='It looks like the payment gateway isn't set up correctly. If you're the store owner, please refer to' order by loc.language_value

Filename: Z:\home\localhost\www\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Please, tell me, how can I fix it? I don't understand where I'm wrong. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hmmmm, [bobby tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't escape string that you're passing to column `label_value`. It contains characters that break the query.

**UPDATE**

This looks like CodeIgniter so you should use:

```
$this->db->escape();
```

Here's the manual

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html

Comment: also, Query bindings is worth mentioning on that same page of the user guide

Answer (score 0):

you should to escape `'` in your string literals

```
'It looks like the payment gateway isn\'t set up correctly. If you\'re the store owner, please refer to'
```

[mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You are building SQL with unescaped strings - the moment one of the strings contains a quote, you're dead. And by dead I mean: If this is a user-supplied value, you just lost control over your database (Google for "SQL injection").

You must escape all strings, that are not known to be OK - Which method to use is a matter of which DB framework you use: It will provide an escaping function.